# Multiple ids with div not working in css

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:

```
 #form1,#form2,#form3,#form5,#form6,#form7,#form8 div{
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color: grey;
    font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,sans-serif;
  }
```

For some reason, the last id does not get the style. (ie #form8 does not get the style).

If I switch the css like this (Without changing any html code):

```
#form1,#form2,#form3,#form5,#form8,#form6,#form7 div{
```

Now #form7 does not have the style.

Did I code the structure wrongly please? Its very strange

Comment: Doesn't work because you select `div` in `#form8`. Try removing `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are targeting div#form1, div#form2 ... and so on... You can skip writing div for the selector. Try this

```
#form1, #form2, #form3, #form5, #form6, #form7, #form8 {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color: grey;
    font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,sans-serif;
}
```

Or even better ... give all of them a class name like `<form class="myform" id="whatever"></form>` and use:

```
.myform {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color: grey;
    font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's probably an HTML markup issue. Can you provide it?

A wild guess is that your code looks like:

```
<div id="form8">
...
</div>
```

And the last part of your CSS selector (#form8 div) actually targets a markup like:

```
<div id="form8">
  <div>
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a meta advice: if your selectors list is so long and apparently targets the same type of element (a form), **use a class**!

```
.form{
padding:10px;
border:1px solid blue;
background-color: grey;
font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: hmm good idea, dont know why I wasnt using a class in the first place. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just use  `#form1,#form2,#form3,#form5,#form6,#form7,#form8`

`#foem8 div` refers to the all child `div`s of the element with this is `#foem8`